# Forgot to run Sysprep before migrating a VM to a new Azure account

Tags: virtual-machines, azure, sysprep, operating-system

I've been tasked with migrating our VMs from our old Azure Account to our new one.

I knew nothing about anything when I started the process a few days ago. I decided the best thing to do was take it one step at a time. So I reassigned our subscription, moved the storage blobs, disassociated the Os's with the old disks and deleted all the VM's. I just created the new disks from the VHDs in the Blob.

The last step was to create an image from the disk so I could make the new VM's.
Turns out, I should have run Sysprep. I didn't.

What. Do. I. Do. Questionmark.

Comment: Create a new VM with the VHD. Sysprep new VM. Deploy production VM's from Sysprepped VHD. Done.

Comment: Waaayyyyy simpler than I thought it would be

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should just need to sysprep any machines you imaged with the un-sysprepped image. Make sure to take an image of one of these to use for a new standard image (This will need to be done after you sysprep and before you boot the system back into the OS for the OOBE or automated configuration.